# How to store REST api payload for user from frontend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to store the payload of REST API calls made by a user in frontend and be able to make the calls to recreate what the user did (like a replay button)

I have the following scenario:

> User opens website.
>
> User picks a product and configures it.

How can I store the REST API calls payload from frontend: Is there a framework that does that? Which database should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can implements it by **state management**.
I think the user data shoud be stored firstly in some state in front-end by using a **Redux** library for example.

Finally you can send the data for a data base (MongoDb for example) to persist the data stored in Redux state.

So, in terms of Data base use, that depends on if you need that data, even when the user close the browser.